# Can an Oracle DB provide an accessing tomcat server's ID when load balancing

Tags: java, database, oracle, quartz

OK, here is the setup:

- I am using Quartz in my Java application.
- The Java application is duplicated for load balancing.
- These duplicates accesses an Oracle DB.
- One quartz job will fire simultaneously on all duplicates, but I only
  want it to run on one due to a race condition. ...and, you know, it's a duplicate.

There are many hack solutions to this. There is even a proper clustering solution to this. However, I am asking for something specific. I want to know if the DB meta/schema can be queried through the quartz job, and have the response be of which server on the load balancer is asking. Some form of identification that was potentially provided to the DB through the driver. Something I could definitively know my unique ID. This way, I can just kill jobs having an ID say > 1, or not serverName xyz, etc.

Comment: It's possible to check if there has another active connection to the database from the other server. You could close current session then. For a better solution you could check https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_appinf.htm#CHECEIEB It is for Oracle 10g, but it is the same for 11g and 12c.

Comment: Are you looking for the host of the client from within the database?  If you are, look at v$session view and the machine column.

Comment: So, believe it or not, I just added a static UUID. it loads when Tomcat loads and provides a unique ID to the instance. I just use it to reserve the action. So... Tomcat 7a9d07a6-2e09-11ed-a261-0242ac120002 has reserved this action and you (are/are not) that Tomcat to take appropriate action.